# CSS stretch div vertically to fill remaining container

Tags: css

It seems so simple, but I wrap my mind about it and googled a lot but couldn't find an answer:

Container with two vertical rows, one has height defined in pixels (header), and the other has image that should stretch as much as remaining height (slider div). The problem is that this height of header is dynamic (as in unknown) and we can't use that value in defining CSS of container or slider div.

How do I solve it without javascript?

```
<section>
  <header style="height:40px; background: yellow;">header</header>
  <div id="slider">  
        <img src="http://amanita-design.net/img/home-news/botanicula.jpg" />
  </div>
</section>


    section {
      position: absolute;         
      top: 0; 
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 400px;
      background: green;
    }
    #slider {
      height: 100%; /* this is wrong; how to set height to stretch element? */
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Header is set to 40px just for the sake of the example. It could be any other value, but the CSS definition of other elements shouldn't be aware of that, because it's dynamically loaded 3rd party component with inline CSS.
Also, slider div is a complex slider (Swiper) that renders code with bunch of nested divs but I need to use exactly that one.

But this DOM structure should be rough sketch of my case.

Example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/snaokLxd/3/

Comment: Old solution would be table, the new solution is flex, but flex does not work on older iphones for example (no need for javascript).

Comment: Can you help me with flex solution? I tried it actually, but failed.

Comment: Flex example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/snaokLxd/4/) - you can put any content after, as footer etc.

Comment: that's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the parent to `flex` with `#slider` set to `flex-grow: 1` (or `flex: 1 0 0` for short)

```css
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#slider {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header style="height:40px; background: yellow;">header</header>
  <div id="slider">
    <img src="http://amanita-design.net/img/home-news/botanicula.jpg" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work, the image is not stretched to fill the height, see it in my updated jsfiddle based on your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/snaokLxd/5/

Comment: @Dalibor sorry I don't know what I was thinking. Meant to add `flex` to `section`, not `body`. updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, but still scrollbar shows a bit. I tried your answer also in codepen, same issue happens: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVWqVW

Comment: that's how images are treated in html. either make it `display: block` or use `vertical-align: top`. That wasn't listed as a requirement in your OP. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/zwBqzV

Comment: This is selected as accepted answer because of the clearer flex definition then the other solution (no offense, skobaljic)

Answer (score 1):

Flex example below:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 400px;
    background: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#slider {
    flex-grow: 2;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <header style="height:40px; background: yellow;">header</header>
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="http://amanita-design.net/img/home-news/botanicula.jpg" />
    </div>
</section>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snaokLxd/4/).

Comment: Glad I helped, sve najbolje poz!

Comment: Sve najbolje i tebi!